# Apache configuration. Website does not work

Tags: server, apache2

I'm trying run website on ubuntu server but it does not work. This is my configuration:

/etc/apache2/sites-available/vtiger

```
<VirtualHost *:33333>
ServerName my.domain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/vtigercrm/
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/vtiger.my.domain.com.error_log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/vtiger.my.domain.com.access_log combined
<Directory /var/www/vtigercrm>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/vtiger

```
<VirtualHost *:33333>
ServerName my.domain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/vtigercrm/
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/vtiger.my.domaincom.error_log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/vtiger.my.domain.com.access_log combined
<Directory /var/www/vtigercrm>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/apache2/ports.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:33333
Listen 33333

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    # If you add NameVirtualHost *:443 here, you will also have to change
    # the VirtualHost statement in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl
    # to <VirtualHost *:443>
    # Server Name Indication for SSL named virtual hosts is currently not
    # supported by MSIE on Windows XP.
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

What is wrong? How to fix it? There are no errors in the logs

I'm trying also run: my.domain.com:33333 but this return:

> The connection has timed out

Comment: Are you getting any error when accesses from the browser?

Comment: @thefourtheye If I run: my.domain.com this load page from my server for example: `144.76.57.14`. My domain is pointing to this IP. Not load page from `/var/www/vtigercrm/`

Comment: Did you restart apache after adding new virtualhost configuration and enabling it?

Comment: Does http://localhost:33333 work?

Comment: Yes. I restarted Apache and `my.domain.com:33333` return `The connection has timed out`

Comment: @saji89 On localhost:33333 work fine!

Comment: @user2307683, Nice. Seems like the server name directive is not getting bind.

Comment: Have you tried checking your configuration running `apachect -S`?